# Order total amount does not include tax amount

Tags: magento2, checkout

Total order amount does not include tax calculation on Shopping Cart

Attaching pic for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Which Magento 2 version are you using?

Comment: @KirtiNariya i am using magento 2.3

Comment: Have you installed any third party extension?

Answer (score 2):

1. Store >> Configuration
2. Sales >> TAX
3. Shopping Cart Display Setting >> Display subtotal set as "Excluding
   Tax"

Answer (score 0):

You should activate **Include Tax In Order Total**

Below is the step:

> Admin -> Stores -> Configuratuion -> Sales -> Tax -> Shopping Cart Display Settings -> Include Tax In Order Total

Make it   **Yes**

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: .........This configuration is already set.Still tax is not included in Order total amount

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Update below section in these two files

**app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grand Total</item>
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
      </item>
</item>
```